# Amazon S3 から FSx for Windows へのファイルコピー方法を教えて下さい

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Lambda (Python) を使用して、S3に保存されたことをトリガーとして FSx for Windows にファイルをコピーしたいです。

しかし、検索エンジンで調べても対象の検索結果が見つかりません。

公式ドキュメントには記載なし：
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/what-is.html

そもそも S3 から FSx for Windows のファイルコピーはLambdaで実装できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

コピーするということは、実はS3からFSx for Windowsへミラーリングしたいということになりますでしょうか？
そうであれば、いっそ [AWS DataSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datasync/latest/userguide/how-datasync-works.html) でS3からFSx for Windowsへ同期してしまえばいいかと思います。あとはこの同期タスクをいつ起動するかで、Lambdaからでも実行すればいいかと。